# Interacting with the Firebase Firestore from a separate Python script without Admin privileges

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I would like to interface with the Firestore from Python in order to fetch some data in a simple script that exists outside of the main application I'm developing. Then I would like to be able to distribute that script to other employees without needing to provide them with a service account that has unlimited access to the database (because it would be a major security risk). I hope that they could authenticate by providing a username and password to the script either through env. variables or on runtime.

Is there any way to authenticate into Firestore from outside of the client application in another way than through an almighty service account?

I was thinking to just login as a regular user (somehow use the auth API just like a client does) but I couldn't find any documentation or example of that and it seems like I'd be reinventing the wheel writing a wrapper around the firebase API that could authenticate a user and fetch a collection. The same goes for writing my own endpoints for the Python script to use - seems like a huge overkill for such a simple scenario (defeats the purpose of a backend as a service).

Comment: I think there are many ways to do it, however I do not understand the use case. What do you mean by "outside of client application" or "login as a regular user"?

Comment: Firebase is meant to operate as backend for a client application - either a web app or a mobile app so I believe it's implied that one exists when someones uses Firebase. And in that case you can use a client library designed for use in client-side JS or android/ios. My problem is to utilize database rules just as if I was authenticating from the client-side but not from a web/mobile environment

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way to do it is with [Google Cloud Function](https://cloud.google.com/functions).

1. First step will be to create such [http triggered function](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/http) in any available language that will be getting as needed from Firestore. If the function is in the same project it will not need authentication at all.
2. Cloud  function uses [Google Cloud IAM to authorize](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/managing-access-iam). So you add members that can invoke the function. So you have to arrange access for all users you need. You can give every user role "Cloud Functions Invoker" just for this function.
3. Than they will be able to invoke the access from their accounts. Than if particular user has [Cloud SDK](https://cloud.google.com/sdk) (`gcloud`) installed and is logged in to her/his own account, she/he can invoke the function ex. with `curl` ([reference](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/authenticating)):

`curl https://REGION-PROJECT_ID.cloudfunctions.net/FUNCTION_NAME \ -H "Authorization: bearer $(gcloud auth print-identity-token)"`

The command is the same for every user so you can make a script of it.

I think this is easiest way, I was able to such create and test such solution in about 15 minutes.

If you are using only [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/), but not Google Cloud Console, that should not be a problem, as Firebase project is in fact Google Cloud Project, so you should have access to it via [Google Cloud Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/).

What more such solution is quite cheap. If the invocation will not count in many millions it may end in [free tier](https://cloud.google.com/functions/pricing#free_tier) or max few $ per month.

Comment: In a way it does and it might indeed be the "easiest" way to do it (if it is, it is the best answer possible) but I'd hope that something that is a backend as a service doesn't need me to extend the backend using Cloud Functions to do something as simple as this.

My intuition is that I'm missing some simple way of resolving my problem (and Cloud Functions are not simple enough) but it might also just be a criticism directed towards Firebase and not this answer.